# Line with an arrow head in Matlab

Tags: matlab, line

I plotted a line with arrowhead in 3D using the ARROW.m script (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278-arrow-m) as follows:

```
figure(1)
clf
hold on;
scatter3(X,Y,Z,'ko')
Z1 = 500;
arrow([max(X) max(Y) Z1],[min(X) min(Y) Z1],15,'BaseAngle',60, 'FaceColor',[0 1 0])
```

However, I want to make outputs (which must contain the line along with arrow head) in X-Z plane; i.e. view([180 0]), not in 3D which is good for visualization only. Unfortunately, though the line is visible, the arrow head is not seen when I go into 2D view. I tried to include 'CrossDir',[0 0 1] as suggested by the author of the script, but it didn't help. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.